# Trying to pair Bluetooth with Windows 7 API return Timeout (Code 258)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, bluetooth

I am trying to replace the Windows Bluetooth pairing. I found some code that was suppose to do this, and I mostly mimiced that code. Although, when I run the code which is below I always get a 258 error code.

Below is the code that does the actual pairing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>


bool BluetoothAuthCallback(LPVOID pvParam, PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS pAuthCallbackParams)
{
     DWORD dwRet;

    fprintf(stderr, "BluetoothAuthCallback 0x%x\n", pAuthCallbackParams->deviceInfo.Address.ullLong);

    dwRet = BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponse(NULL, &(pAuthCallbackParams->deviceInfo), L"1234");
    if(dwRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponse ret %d\n", dwRet);
        ExitProcess(2);
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "BluetoothAuthCallback finish\n");
    ExitProcess(0);
    return 1;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SOCKADDR_BTH sa = { 0 };
    int sa_len = sizeof(sa);
    DWORD dwRet;
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO  btdi = {0};
    HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION hRegHandle = 0;

    // initialize windows sockets
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD( 2, 0 );
    if( WSAStartup( wVersionRequested, &wsaData ) != 0 ) {
        ExitProcess(2);
    }

   // parse the specified Bluetooth address
    if( argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: rfcomm-client <addr>\n"
            "\n  addr must be in the form (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX)");
        ExitProcess(2);
    }
    if( SOCKET_ERROR == WSAStringToAddress( argv[1], AF_BTH,
            NULL, (LPSOCKADDR) &sa, &sa_len ) ) {
        ExitProcess(2);
    }
    btdi.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);
    btdi.Address.ullLong = sa.btAddr;
    btdi.ulClassofDevice = 0;
    btdi.fConnected = false;
    btdi.fRemembered = false;
    btdi.fAuthenticated = false;

    dwRet = BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx(&btdi, &hRegHandle,  (PFN_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_EX)&BluetoothAuthCallback, NULL);
    if(dwRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx ret %d\n", dwRet);
        ExitProcess(2);
    }

    dwRet = BluetoothAuthenticateDeviceEx(NULL, NULL, &btdi, NULL,MITMProtectionNotRequired);
    if(dwRet != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BluetoothAuthenticateDevice ret %d\n", dwRet);
        ExitProcess(2);
    }

    Sleep(1000);
    fprintf(stderr, "pairing finish\n");
    ExitProcess(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Below this is how I find the address to pass into the pairing application.

```
// BluetoothAddressFinder.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <initguid.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO m_bt_info = {sizeof(BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO),0,};

    BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS m_bt_find_radio = {sizeof(BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS)};
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO m_device_info = {sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO),0,};
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS m_search_params = {
        sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
        1, 0,
        1,1,1,15,NULL
};
    HANDLE m_radio = NULL;
    HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND m_bt = NULL;
    HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND m_bt_dev = NULL;
    int m_radio_id;
    DWORD mbtinfo_ret;
    int tempNumberOfDevices = 0;

    m_bt = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio);

    m_radio_id = 0;

    do {
        // Then get the radio device info....
        mbtinfo_ret = BluetoothGetRadioInfo(m_radio, &m_bt_info);
        // If there was an issue with the current radio check the next radio
        if(mbtinfo_ret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            continue;

        m_search_params.hRadio = m_radio;
        ZeroMemory(&m_device_info, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));
        m_device_info.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);

        // Next for every radio, get the device
        m_bt_dev = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&m_search_params, &m_device_info);

        // Get the device info
        do {
            tempNumberOfDevices+=1;
            fprintf(stdout, "Device name: %S Device Address: %d:%d:%d:%d:%d:%d \n" ,m_device_info.szName,m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5],m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0] );

        } while(BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, &m_device_info));

    } while(BluetoothFindNextRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio));


}
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? Trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Did the find BT radio code work?